# Express.js and Basic Angular Experience

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, node.js

I hope you will consider my question here.

I'm a `PHP` developer, mostly `laravel`, and have some basic `AngularJS` knowledge like `routing`, `directives` and `resource`. I'm using `Laravel` as my back end and `Angular` as my front end to create single page websites and also `restful` web services.

Now, I'm really interested in learning the full-stack JavaScript solution `MEAN.JS`. A while ago I watched how `express.js` works, and find it to be very nice.

Can I learn `Node` and `Express` at the same time with a minimal `Angular` knowledge also to make `meanjs` applications? Or should I really learn it one by one before I go the full-stack solution?

Hoping for your kind consideration on my post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: for my knowledge, you can learn node and express simultaneously.

Comment: @FewFly did my answer provide you the information you were looking for? If so please mark it as correct. If no please provide your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to basically learn Express with node as Node is a dependency. I started out with Mean.js and Mean.io but those apps combine the front and backend too tightly. In hindsight I wish I learned to build a pure REST API using Express / Node first then add a front end. Check out the Yeoman generators: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

You can use express / node without angular and just have a server side REST API. If you plan on continuing with MEAN.JS their examples are decent but my biggest hurdle like I said is that the separation from Server and Client side could have been cleaner. Your minimal knowledge of Angular is fine. I would recommend looking into using Restangular instead of ngResource. It is awesome.

Comment: Thanks. I will go to this after I learned some basics of Node I guess